# Junit Testing for Criteria in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, testing, junit, criteria

I have been working on an opensource software project.I am working on a bug in that project. For that I need to write an unit test.

I have searched the internet for any related materials. But I was unable to find something. I need to know how to write an unit test for for a method which has a return type Criteria. I know How to make it work for a String or an Integer. I am confused with the Criteria return type since I am quite not sure about it's format.

Comment: You can explore what that Criteria contains.. right?

Comment: Hmmm, I am not clear about it.